# F# Binary Tree Insert type Error

Tags: f#, binary-tree

I'm working on a simple BST implementation in F# and have hit a stumbling block that I can't find my way around.

This code:

```
type BST =
| Empty
| TreeNode of int * BST * BST

let rec insert value tree = function
    | Empty -> TreeNode(value, Empty, Empty)
    | TreeNode(hd, left, right) as node ->
        if hd = value then node
        elif value < hd then TreeNode(hd, insert value left, right)
        else TreeNode(hd, left, insert value right)
```

Results in the following error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have
type
'BST'     

but here has type
'BST -> BST'
```

Which is referring to these two lines of code

```
elif value < hd then TreeNode(hd, insert value left, right)
else TreeNode(hd, left, insert value right)
```

specifically the recursive calls `... insert value left, ...` and `... insert value right)`

I don't understand F# well enough to understand why this is a problem for the compiler. When it executes shouldn't that value resolve to just type BST? Isn't that the whole point of this type of recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let f = function
| ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
let f x =
    match x with
    | ...
```

so you are defining `insert` to take 3 parameters instead of the two you intend. Your `insert` has type `int -> 'a -> BST -> BST` so you aren't supplying enough parameters to the recursive call, hence the error. Since you want to match on the structure of the tree, remove the `tree` parameter i.e.

```
let rec insert value = function
    | Empty -> TreeNode(value, Empty, Empty)
    | TreeNode(hd, left, right) as node ->
        if hd = value then node
        elif value < hd then TreeNode(hd, insert value left, right)
        else TreeNode(hd, left, insert value right)
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to structuring a pattern-match function the second way over the first way, or vice versa?

Comment: It's shorter. Otherwise, exactly equivalent.

Comment: @user3776749 Yes, using `function` is more obfuscated and prone to errors like yours.